# writing a simple linear (and logistic) regression equation that incorporates survey weights

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, survey-weights

I am running a basic linear (and then logistic) regression that incorporates basic survey weights. I would like to specify the general regression equation with the survey weights for a manuscript. But I cannot find an easily interpretable article that shows what a regression line of the form $y=a+xb+u$ looks like with notation with a survey weight added. Basic general linear model with a survey weight. That's all. Can anyone point me in the right direction? For a logistic regression as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model is

- in the population $Y=a+bX+u$; plus
- $E[R_i]=\pi_i$, where $R_i$ is the indicator that individual $i$ was sampled and $1/\pi_i$ is the sampling weight.

That is, the model combines two assumptions: a linear model in the population and correct specification of the sampling probabilities.

The weights don't go into the linear specification at all, they go only into the sampling part of the model.

[In fact, some people working in survey analysis would argue that the first assumption isn't actually needed. That is, they would say the **only** model assumption is correct specification of sampling probabilities, and that the linear 'model' is just a choice of summary statistic and not a model assumption.]